# Read from HID device

Tags: linux, hid, lsusb

I have remote HID device but seems to be constantly reconnected.
Is there a way to use it on linux? For windows computer the driver is available but not for linux. I assume it's possible to be used but doesn't have clue how.

I try to list devices with python code like:

```
import evdev

devices = [evdev.InputDevice(fn) for fn in evdev.list_devices()]
print (devices)
for device in devices:
    print(device.fn, device.name, device.phys)
```

but script doesn't list any device. Appear that device is constantly reconnected. Here is lsusb and dmesg output:

```
xxx@yyy:~$ lsusb -v -d6125:2012

Bus 003 Device 106: ID 6125:2012 Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0
  bDeviceSubClass         0
  bDeviceProtocol         0
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x6125
  idProduct          0x2012
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1
  iProduct                2
  iSerial                 3
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0029
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0
      bInterfaceProtocol      0
      iInterface              4
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      26
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               2
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               2
xxx@yyy:~$
```

and dmesg output:

```
[429762.438205] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[429762.652341] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429762.652344] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429762.652346] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429762.652348] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429762.652350] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429762.656084] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0926: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429763.521113] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 17
[429763.842171] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[429764.056330] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429764.056333] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429764.056336] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429764.056338] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429764.056340] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429764.060064] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0927: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429764.929078] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 18
[429765.254126] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
[429765.468321] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429765.468324] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429765.468326] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429765.468328] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429765.468330] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429765.471962] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0928: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429766.336910] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 19
[429766.662072] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 20 using ehci-pci
[429766.876312] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429766.876316] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429766.876318] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429766.876319] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429766.876321] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429766.880257] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0929: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429767.745028] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 20
[429768.070038] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 21 using ehci-pci
[429768.284303] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429768.284307] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429768.284309] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429768.284311] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429768.284313] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429768.288110] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.092A: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429769.153078] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 21
[429769.474034] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 22 using ehci-pci
[429769.688292] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429769.688296] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429769.688298] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429769.688299] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429769.688301] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429769.692092] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.092B: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429770.561074] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 22
[429770.882003] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 23 using ehci-pci
[429771.096284] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429771.096287] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429771.096289] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429771.096291] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429771.096293] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429771.100080] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.092C: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429771.969058] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 23
[429772.293959] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 24 using ehci-pci
[429772.508293] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429772.508297] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429772.508299] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429772.508301] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429772.508302] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429772.512198] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.092D: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429773.377049] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 24
[429773.701934] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 25 using ehci-pci
[429773.916283] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429773.916286] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429773.916289] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429773.916291] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429773.916292] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429773.920187] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.092E: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429774.785037] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 25
[429775.109902] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 26 using ehci-pci
[429775.324275] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429775.324278] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429775.324280] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429775.324282] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429775.324284] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429775.328214] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.092F: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429776.193028] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 26
[429776.513871] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 27 using ehci-pci
[429776.728265] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429776.728268] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429776.728270] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429776.728272] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429776.728273] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429776.732205] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0930: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429777.601020] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 27
[429777.925836] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 28 using ehci-pci
[429778.140111] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429778.140114] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429778.140116] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429778.140118] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429778.140120] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429778.143890] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0931: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429779.009010] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 28
[429779.329802] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 29 using ehci-pci
[429779.543974] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429779.543977] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429779.543980] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429779.543982] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429779.543983] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429779.547786] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0932: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429780.417007] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 29
[429780.741783] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 30 using ehci-pci
[429780.955815] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429780.955817] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429780.955818] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429780.955819] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429780.955820] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429780.959480] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0933: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429781.824855] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 30
[429782.149748] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
[429782.363814] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429782.363818] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429782.363820] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429782.363822] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429782.363823] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429782.368627] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0934: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429783.232987] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 31
[429783.557677] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 32 using ehci-pci
[429783.771817] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429783.771820] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429783.771821] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429783.771822] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429783.771823] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429783.775468] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0935: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429784.640979] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 32
[429784.965668] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 33 using ehci-pci
[429785.179938] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429785.179942] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429785.179944] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429785.179946] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429785.179948] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429785.183878] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0936: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429786.048962] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 33
[429786.373619] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 34 using ehci-pci
[429786.587785] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429786.587789] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429786.587791] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429786.587793] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429786.587794] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429786.591608] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0937: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429787.456934] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 34
[429787.777656] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 35 using ehci-pci
[429787.991920] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429787.991924] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429787.991926] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429787.991928] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429787.991929] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429787.995979] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0938: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429788.864945] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 35
[429789.189571] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 36 using ehci-pci
[429789.403788] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429789.403791] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429789.403793] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429789.403795] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429789.403796] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429789.407883] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.0939: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
[429790.272906] usb 1-1.5.1.4: USB disconnect, device number 36
[429790.601520] usb 1-1.5.1.4: new full-speed USB device number 37 using ehci-pci
[429790.819778] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=6125, idProduct=2012, bcdDevice= 1.00
[429790.819782] usb 1-1.5.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[429790.819784] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Product: Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver
[429790.819786] usb 1-1.5.1.4: Manufacturer: Friendess Technology
[429790.819788] usb 1-1.5.1.4: SerialNumber: 201301300001
[429790.823860] hid-generic 0003:6125:2012.093A: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Friendess Technology Cypcut Wireless USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5.1.4/input0
```

Comment: Try to pass `autosuspend=-1` parameter to `usbcore` module.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. (GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1")